# How to import contacts from OS X address book to Thunderbird in Ubuntu?

Tags: thunderbird, macosx

I want to export from address book in Mac OS X and import to the address book in Thunderbird mail in Ubuntu. I exported the contacts as `vCards.vcf` and imported it fine but now I just have 36 blank entries in the address book in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use the Address Book Exporter 2.1.2 to export from the Mac OS X address book into a ".txt" file and then import into Thunderbird. Make sure to use the Yahoo option. This method is still not perfect but you can get it to work after a little bit of cut & pasting.

See [this MozillaZine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_Mac_OS_X_address_book) for more information