# Contacts / Address Book equivalent to OS X 'Contacts'

Tags: contacts

This is more a suggestion/observation than a straight question.
As most elderly people I started with DOS, then Windows but after that I switched to OS X and now, I would like to (at 73 years old) quit the Wonderful World of Apple.

I have my whole life (at the moment) on my Mac and I've had Ubuntu installed on my spare MacBook Pro. I'm now in the process "fiddling/learning" my way to be able to transfer my life to Ubuntu.

The one application I find missing in Ubuntu is the equivalent of "OS X Contacts". The only Ubuntu compatible application I've found is Thunderbird which, in my opinion has an unpractical "Address Book" divided into bits by thumbnails, a few of which I have no use for and which in addition seems impossible to modify, in addition OS X (and iPhone) notes don't transfer to the Thunderbird Address-Book on my Mac.

So my question is: why is something so apparently simple as a list of contact V cards (everything on one card including notes,and sync-able with a smart-phone) missing in such an otherwise complete and well made OS as Ubuntu?

Thanks for reading

Bob

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot answer why a certain software doesn't exist within the scope of this site.

Comment: The actual question being asked (final paragraph) is "Why is some piece of software not included?", which I think is either too broad or primarily opinion based.

Comment: I'd love to know where you settled with this. I, too, am looking for a carddav sync client that isn't Thunderbird or Evolution, so I can have a free standing address book that syncs with OwnCloud and then with my phone.

Comment: Yes, PIM (personal information management) in Linux is broken and it is the main reason why Linux never was successful as a Desktop & Workstation OS. Cal-/Card-DAV which was originally designed by Apple (RFC 6352) is violated by themselves, to make it only work on their own devices and OS. A similar strategy, known as "lock-in", has been successfully followed by Microsoft for years!
There needs to be a proper PIM framework to be designed and released under a functional open source license in order to fight and win this "Big Dada" battle!

Answer (score 1):

[image: GNOME Contacts logo]

Ubuntu ships with the [GNOME Contacts](https://apps.gnome.org/en-GB/Contacts/) app now. If it's not installed, install it by running:

```
sudo apt install gnome-contacts
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Evolution Address book.
Add it in Software Center or from terminal - `sudo apt-get install evolution`

Or use Kontact from KDE desktop - can be installed with `sudo apt-get install kontact`.

Smartphone should sync with online services, no need to sync contacts with pc!

Personally i prefer Thunderbird.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've never heard of Dulme nor found it during my searches. As for Thunderbird the "Notes" part of Contacts have to be added one by one manually and I have 1,800 "contacts"! KDE had so many negative "appreciations" That I didn't investigate it any further. Now with your help I have one more to submit to the Geeks at our local Linux/Ubuntu meeting next Friday. At the moment the only thing stopping me from making the jump across to Ubuntu is the lack of a Contacts application.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really based on what type of contact manager you are really looking for, each one is going to have a different feel and take some getting use to for a life-time user of one type of manager. If you do not like Thunderbird **try other ones in the Software Center.(Like Dlume)** [image]

If you are having issues transferring your contacts open a new question on how to transfer contacts 
([OS X Contacts -> Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115596/how-to-import-contacts-from-os-x-address-book-to-thunderbird-in-ubuntu)) I use `address-book-app` on 14.04. I personally never have used the contact manager layout on Mac so to suggest a manager to try wouldn't really help. Look around in the software center find a layout that fits you and then go to working on transferring contacts with a new question for that application. Hope This helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found KAddressBook to be the one most compatible with importing vcard contacts from Mac. You'll find it in Ubuntu Software. Enjoy!